# Is AND clause supported in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute below query in HIVE.

```
select plc 
 from processed p 
WHERE p.day=26 
  AND p.time_id = 41;
```

But, I get no results . But, upon executing the below query ,i get valid result

```
select plc from processed p WHERE p.day=26
```

I have checked my table and it contains corresponding to `day = 26 and time_id = 41`. Does Hive not support multiple AND clause?

Comment: i am not expert but check for data type of columns

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select shows that Hive does support AND clauses. In particular, their first example of a WHERE clause includes AND:

```
WHERE Clause

The WHERE condition is a boolean expression. For example, the following query returns only those sales records which have an amount greater than 10 from the US region. Hive supports a number of operators and UDFs in the WHERE clause:
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE amount > 10 AND region = "US"
```